# jQuery toggle animation doesn't work on new jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, toggle

I have problem with this toggle on jQuery 1.8.2 i works but on 1.11.0 no. Can you help me what is wrong?

```
$('.open').toggle(function () {
    $('.obj').animate({
        top: "0"
    }, 500);
},function () {
    $('.obj').animate({
        top: "-8%",
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: That method was removed, of course. You'll instead have to use .click and modify the way you're animating.

Comment: Removed in 1.9. http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: Luckily no one ever upgrades jQuery on enterprise level systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you will need to do this using the click method.
Here is an example that uses the element's data to store the state:

```
$('.open').on('click', function(){
    var isToggled = $(this).data('isToggled');
    if(isToggled){
        $('.obj').animate({
            top: "-8%",
        }, 500);
    } else {
      $('.obj').animate({
            top: "0"
        }, 500);
    } 

    $(this).data('isToggled', !isToggled)
});
```