# Jquery Animate is behaving abnormally when I upgrade to 1.11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please Check http://jsfiddle.net/integerz/k19x8L1b/2/ Which has 1.7.x

```
$(function () {
    $("#clickme").toggle(function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'0px'});
    }, function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({right:'-280px'});
    });
});
```

as jquery and http://jsfiddle.net/integerz/k19x8L1b/3/ has 1.11.x

The first one works well. But the second one is not. Can you explain what is the issue?

2. With Absolute DIV why there is a horizontal scroller for the negative right margin?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31899245/toggle-in-latest-jquery-releases-has-been-deprecated-beacause-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1):

It seems the function is discontinued.

Need to do do click like given in this example.

[jQuery toggle animation doesn't work on new jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391620/jquery-toggle-animation-doesnt-work-on-new-jquery)

But not very sure why it was discontinued. Was very handy.

Comment: Have an upvote for finding the solution yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I should have searched better to get the answer from other solutions.

Comment: But I still want to know why there is a horizontal scroller.

Comment: You have to hide body overflow like this  `html,body{overflow-x:hidden;}`